# Assign count value from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple select like this, how can i assign the count of the select statement to @count

```
DECLARE @count int
SELECT Tag FROM @Tags intersect SELECT Tag from @TagsFromRecord

set @count= (select count(1) 
             from (SELECT Tag 
                   FROM @Tags 
                   intersect 
                   SELECT Tag 
                   from @TagsFromRecord))  >> incorrect syntax
```

or

```
select @count= count(1) from (SELECT Tag 
                              FROM @Tags 
                              intersect 
                              SELECT Tag 
                              from @TagsFromRecord)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an allias:

```
DECLARE @count int

set @count= 
(
    select count(1) 
    from 
    (
        SELECT Tag FROM @Tags 
        intersect 
        SELECT Tag from @TagsFromRecord
    ) AS T
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this also would work,

```
DECLARE @count int

select @count = count(1) 
from 
(
    SELECT Tag FROM @Tags 
    intersect 
    SELECT Tag from @TagsFromRecord
) AS T
```

Comment: Use of direct `SELECT` instead of `SET` ;-)

Comment: i think you just got inspired from @jyparask answer and done slight modification

Comment: That was mine (jyparask) interpretation of what is the difference hehe. Anyway, this is a valid answer as it shows a `slightly` but yet different way of doing it.

Comment: you are correct @jyparask , ur ans is correct, I should have commented rather than posting a new answer. + from mysde to ur ans.